# How can I change style of default errors in Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have this default Laravel code for login:

```html
   @error('email')
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
             <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
        </span>
   @enderror
```

how can I change `$message` colour, for example? Where can I find styles or sth? Default `app.css` has been deleted btw, there s nothing in there.

Comment: Inline css : `<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert" style="color : blue">` blue color

Comment: yes. worked. thanks. can y make this comment like an answer to I mark y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An internal style sheet used if one single HTML page has a unique style.
Inline styles are defined within the `style` attribute of the relevant element:

```
<span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert" style="color : blue">
   <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
</span>
```